# Sidebar in AppLayout autoclosing

Tags: typescript, hilla

I have a basic Hilla application, but I am not able to make the sidebar of the AppLayout close when selecting a diferent element. ¿How can I make it work?

I have tried modifying the aria-expanded atribute of the DrawerToggle component, but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.